# Is it always possible to find $X\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\text{Pois}(\mu)$ with given $P(X<Y)$, $P(X=Y)$ and $P(X>Y)$?

Tags: poisson-distribution, skellam-distribution

Consider $P(X<Y)$, $P(X=Y)$ and $P(X>Y)$ in $(0,1)$ that sum to $1$.

Is it always possible to find Poisson parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that independent $X\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\text{Pois}(\mu)$ satisfy these conditions? (Equivalently, such that the corresponding [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) has the specified probability mass over the negative, zero and positive numbers.)

[This was inspired by the discussion in this thread, where it was found that this is *not* always possibly with an additional condition for the sum $\lambda+\mu$ to equal a given number.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/469936/1352)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start:
If $P(X<Y)=P(Y>X)$ then $\lambda=\mu$ and 
$$P(X=Y)=\sum_i \frac{e^{-2\lambda}\lambda^{2i}}{x!^2}$$
which is 1 when $\lambda=\mu=0$ and decreases smoothly to zero as $\lambda=\mu\to\infty$ and so can be solved for any desired $P(X=Y)$, so we can get any $P(X<Y)=P(Y>X)$ we want (I tried unsuccessfully to get a counterexample this way).

Can we generalise?  Suppose that instead we want a ratio $P(X<Y)=kP(Y>X)$ (for unspecified Ps). For any specified $\lambda$ we can find a $\mu$ to make $P(Y>X)$ as large as we like ($\mu\to\infty$) or as small as we like ($\mu\to 0$). So we have a continuous function $\lambda_k(\mu)$ and invoke the intermediate value theorem again.

Now, can we still get $P(X=Y)$ to be whatever we like? Obviously we will be able to for $k$ near enough to 1, so consider $k$ very large. We need $\lambda \gg \mu$. The potential problem is that if $\lambda \gg \mu$ we might need $\lambda$ large enough to force $P(X=Y)$ to be small, or $\mu$ small enough to force $P(X=Y)$ to be large.

The first is not a problem.  We can take $P(X=Y)$ as large as we like (say $1-\epsilon$) by taking $\lambda$ and $\mu$ small. For very small $\epsilon$, then, $$P(X<Y)\approx P(X=0 \& Y=1)\approx e^{-\lambda}(1-e^{-\mu})\approx e^{-\lambda}$$
and $P(Y>X)\approx e^{-\mu}$. There's no problem in choosing $e^{-\lambda}=ke^{-\mu}$

And the second is not a problem. We can take $P(X=Y)$ as small as we like, and still have $P(X<Y)$ anywhere we like.

So for any $\mu$ we can obtain $P(X>Y)=kP(Y>X)$ by setting $\lambda=\lambda_k(\mu)$, and then choose $\mu$ to get $P(X=Y)$ as large or small as we like.

There might well be a way to make $\lambda_k(\mu)$ explicit for $\mu$ that isn't tiny, but I don't see it right now.

Comment: Are these functions monotonic? Would that imply there is a single solution $(\lambda,\mu)$ in each case?

Comment: There is a single solution, because for any $\lambda$, $P(X>Y)$ is strictly decreasing in $\mu$